# Override tomcat basic authentication using java in my web project

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, forms-authentication, web-development-server

I am currently using tomcat authentication overriding class jdbcRealm in server.xml instead of that i want to override tomcat authentication using java.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can disable tomcat authentication and implement authentication filter: https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/how-to-implement-authentication-filter-for-java-web-application
But you didn't say much about your application. Do you use Spring or some other framework?

Comment: no i didnt use any framework. i am trying to understand how to override realm class in tomcat and want to authenticate using new realm class.